# Hartshorne Lemma (II.4.5): f(X) is closed iff stable under specialization

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have some questions about the proof of the following lemma:

> Let $f: X\to Y$ be a quasi-compact morphism of schemes and suppose that $f(X)$ is stable under specialization. Then $f(X)$ is closed.

In the proof, he firstly reduces this lemma to the case that $X$ and $Y$ are both reduced, Y is affine and $f$ is dominant. hence it is enough to show that $f$ is surjective in this condition.

I can understand how can he reduce to this condition, but I have some questions about the following process:

> Since $X$ can be covered by a finite union of open affines $X_i$, $y\in \overline{f(X_i)}$ for some $i$.  Let $Y_i=\overline{f(X_i)}$ with the reduced induced structure, then we will consider the dominant morphism $X_i\to Y_i$ of reduced affine schemes.

My question is:

We reduce to the case that $f: X\to Y$ is a dominant quasi-compact morphism of schemes, and $Y$ is affine (I understand why we can reduce to this condition).  If $f(X)$ is stable under specialization, how can we show that $f(X_i)$ is stable under specialization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If $f(X)$ is stable under specialization, how can we show that $f(X_i)$ is stable under specialization?

That is not claimed to be true, and actually wrong. For example consider the map $f: \mathbb A^1 \sqcup \mathbb P^1 \to \mathbb P^1$, which includes $\mathbb A^1$ as a standard open, and is the identity on $\mathbb P^1$. The image of $f$ is all of $\mathbb P^1$, so stable under specialization and closed. But the restriction $\mathbb A^1 \to \mathbb P^1$ is neither. (To make the codomain affine, restrict to some standard open which is different from the one chosen for $f$).

Note that Hartshorne uses $\overline{f(X_i)}$ to construct some point $y' \in f(X_i)$ which specializes to $y$, then concludes $y \in f(X)$, as $f(X)$ is closed under specialization. And this still works in the example above, even if you take for $X_i$ the open $\mathbb A^1 \subset \mathbb A^1 \sqcup \mathbb P^1$.